# Installing Kubuntu on PC without internet connection

Tags: installation, kubuntu

I need to install Kubuntu LTS version on x86 notebook. Current version is numbered 12.04.1. Unfortunately my internet connection is somewhat limited so I can download max. 1 GB per month. Now what are my options? I checked this web page:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

On the bottom of the page is directory listing. Most ISO images have size ~700 MB. I can download it at work or at friend, its no problem. But I am not sure if this small image contains all binaries needed to create usable system (at least in minimalistic version including graphical user interface, OpenOffice, Firefox browser and media player)? Is there somewhere more swelled version of setup program (lets say on 2 - 3 DVDs) containing selection of frequently used packages?

Answer (score 1):

You may download the Ubuntu iso and burn it to a DVD. The installation procedure asks you if you want to download updates while installing. This will download quite an amount of Mb, you may choose not to and install the updates gradually once the system is installed.

The DVD contains a web browser, LibreOffice and a lot more out of the box, but it is recommended to install updates afterwards.

If you do not want to waste bandwidth with the updates you may use one of various options to download the updates and install them while offline. You may use [Keryx](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/keryx-offline-package-installation-made-easy-in-ubuntu) or [Synaptic](http://techspalace.blogspot.fr/2009/04/offline-update-ubuntu.html) amongst the options available.